# javascript issue when putting code into a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

It could be because its late, but I've been at this for a good while now and still getting no further and running out of time.

Basically when I move the following code:

```
    var test = "hell";
           $('#qrcodeCanvas').qrcode({ text: test });
```

out from the function method and into the script it works fine, but if I put it within the button click function I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I need it to work on button click, Here is the main code involved:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/lib/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/qrcode.js"></script>


    <div id="first">
          <p>hello</p>
        <input type="text" id="qr-text"  value=""  placeholder="Enter QR Data..."/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button id="button">Click on button</button>

    </div>

        <div id="qrcodeCanvas"></div>


   <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#button').click(function () {
               var test = "hell";
               $('#qrcodeCanvas').qrcode({ text: test });
           });
       });
</script>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the js file in question: http://jquer.in/javascript-and-jquery-solutions-for-fantastic-mobile-websites/qr-code/

Comment: Have you tried: `$('#qrcodeCanvas').qrcode(test);`

Comment: yes, with the js file, it needs to be format i have in the answer, i also initial thought it was the problem, but further investigation found it needed the text: before it

Comment: Where the documentation for this: jquery.qrcode.js? Found 4 different ones so far and not sure which is the right one

Comment: try `$('#qrcodeCanvas').qrcode({ "text": test });`

Comment: Could you share the qrcode.js file or any reference? It looks like it is a scope issue.

Comment: http://jquer.in/javascript-and-jquery-solutions-for-fantastic-mobile-websites/qr-code/

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/42q99fvc/

Comment: @RickHitchcock error 404 on opening the jsfiddle

Comment: Please note that [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*, whereas I inferred from your script references that you're using the specific ASP.NET implementation and adjusted your tags accordingly.

Comment: Unless someone else can confirm the 404 error, you may be having firewall or other network issues.

Comment: @RickHitchcock fiddle opens for me just fine.

Comment: Works fine with jsFiddle. It might be because you messed the jquery.qrcode.js file or anyother script file. Here is the fiddle link                            http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/08kq6fek/

Comment: use cdns instead of loading script from local file. It will work

Comment: May be off topic: Another scenario where this problem arises when someone have multiple `jquery` instance loaded in same page or may be `$` is reserved for some other library.

Comment: i tried everyones suggestions and still an issue, here is a more in-depth error on google debugger http://postimg.org/image/mdb5ug8or/

Comment: can wee access your web page?

Comment: Use chrome console to see under network tab if your `qrcode plugin` file is really loaded.

Comment: The website is not accessible, intranet so it is. Yes it does load. I can't understand why the JavaScript works fine outside of the button click function but when I put it in it fails, baffles me ha

Comment: I think you need a width and height. If you're on localhost you'll need to use an Absolute Path to access files outside of your local Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use the "un-minified" version, you need to load `qrcode.js` **first**. If you use the `jquery.qrcode.min.js` version, it packs the `qrcode.js` code into the same file.

So instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/qrcode.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qrcode.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
```